# Set up two Kali Linux OSs in VirtualBox and ping between them

Tags: virtualbox, ping, kali-linux, tethering, bridged

I have VirtualBox installed in Windows 8. In VirtualBox I have two Kali Linux 2.0 OSs. Both have access to the internet, but I can't seem to ping them. My home computer uses cell phone tethering for internet and not a router. I'm having issues with whether to use bridged or host networking options in VirtualBox. The IP addresses are coming back the same, and I need to ping the address of one Kali Linux system from the other, all inside of VirtualBox.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your setup?  Are you talking about two VBs on the same computer or two separate computers?  Is the second Debian a temporary installation just to run some tests?  What is the host OS?

Comment: The home computer is windows 8. I have Virtual box. inside virtual box I have two kali linux 2.0. both have access to internet but I cant seem to ping them

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use a Router for test the two kali Linux.

May be it will work by change the host-only to link the internal network!

you can following this!

step1:
**setting:**

step2:
**network:**

step3:
**Host-only Adapter**

[image: Host-only screenshot]